# Python: NameError - what should I do with this?

Tags: python, module, class

I am working on a large-scale software system that is written in Python right now.

The thing is, I am not sure how to make sure if each individual .py file in the system is correct. The only way for me to run the software is to run the main.py file, which uses all the other .py files.

So either everything works, or one thing doesn't (causing everything to not work).

I keep getting a NameError even when importing the correct file. I think this may have to do with the fact that the class associated with that name in the NameError may have errors in it. Any suggestions? NameError is giving me this:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'RGBox' is not defined
```

It's not a very helpful error message, and I'm not sure why it's giving "string" and 'module' instead of actual values.....

[EDIT]- I am working through ssh into a remote unix machine

Comment: Would you by try the verbose and give more information on the error `python -v <file you are trying to run`. Also would you be able to give information on the first import lines on the files?

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight-forward error message which indicates that the execution flow has not yet encountered class/module/variable `RGBox` prior to it being called.

`RGBox` is either being called out of sequence or has been mispelt.

Perform a commandline search through the app files for the name 'RGBox' or its regex equivalents. for example with `grep` you can do a case-insensitive search:

```
$ grep -lsri 'rgbox' ./my_project_folder
```

which will output any file which contains the patterns 'RGBox', 'rgBox', etc.

If you are unfamiliar with the code and its structure, then you may as well insert strategic logging (or `print`) statements at significant locations in the code to understand its flow and execution logic.